# How can I use nested loop for widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand I can code like single loop to build widget like;

```
final icon =["lock.png","map.png","stake.png","cheer.png","sushi.png"];
// omit
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
        for(int i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) ... {
          selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: icon[i]),
        },
  ],
),
```

But when those widgets structured as nested like:

```
final icon =["lock.png","map.png","stake.png","cheer.png","sushi.png","drink.png","toy.png","christmas.png","newyear.png","flag.png")];
//omit,
child: Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "lock.png"),
        selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "map.png"),
        selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "sushi.png"),
        selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "stake.png"),
        selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "cheer.png"),
      ],
    ),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "drink.png"),
          selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "toy.png"),
          selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "christmas.png"),
          selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "newyear.png"),
          selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: "flag.png"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ]
);
```

How can I build with nested widget with loop in flutter / Dart ? or is it unacceptable ?

Comment: where did you find such strange form like `... { selectIcon() }`? instead just use `selectIcon()` after `for` loop

Comment: I don't see any "Nested" data structure here, only an simple Array.

Comment: @pskink it is selfdefied class, and sorry for inadequate explanation

Comment: @Tuan Nesting things are just for widgets but not data itself, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package to split your icon into lists that have 5 items in them like this:

```
class _CustomTitleWidgetState extends State<CustomTitleWidget> {
  final icon = [
    "lock.png",
    "map.png",
    "stake.png",
    "cheer.png",
    "sushi.png",
    "drink.png",
    "toy.png",
    "christmas.png",
    "newyear.png",
    "flag.png"
  ];

  Widget selectIcon({required int id, required String iconPass}) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(iconPass),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var iconChunks = icon.slices(5).toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
          children: iconChunks
              .map((e) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children:
                          e.map((e) => selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: e)).toList(),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, and may I ask Should I user `map()` but not `for` or I cannot user `for` sentence the case above ?

Comment: I recommended use map, I didn't see for loop in this situation.

Comment: icon is already a list - so it is simple to produce a list of Widgets using map and toList. For is useful when you don't have a list to begin with - for example - you need to put 5 Text widgets in children. You can use List.generate, but for perhaps looks better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if the number of items in icon[] are unpredictable how should I use getRage(X,Y) like this case ?

Comment: it depends on how do you want to split them in two list.You want to split them in half and git them to those row?  @SugiuraY

Comment: I'm sorry that I should explain accurately

Comment: 1. I can not predict the number of items in icon[] map

Comment: 2. and row object contains five items at most

Comment: 3.so If there are more than six items in  icon[], it should structered with several rows

Comment: you mean if the icons have 15 items, you want 3 rows each contains 5 items? @SugiuraY

Comment: 4. for example, if 16 items exist in unpredictable icon[], there are 4 rows and five items for 1st to 3rd row and one item for 4th row.

Comment: yes I do mean that. I expressed it as nested widgets but sorry that was not good way to ask

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out @SugiuraY

Comment: this is really impressive way for me and I should say super super thank you! I could not imagine in this way..

Comment: and thanks for complete my selfdefined class which I have not disclosed!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `List.generate` to generate a list of widgets.

```
final icon = [
  "lock.png",
  "map.png",
  "stake.png",
  "cheer.png",
  "sushi.png"
];

Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: List.generate(
    icon.length,
    (i) => selectedIcon(
      id: 1,
      iconPass: icon[i]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, this is first time to know how to generate a list of widgets!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it dynamically, and works with an item list of any size. It will group your items in groups of 5

```
    Column(
        children: [
          for(int i = 0; i < icon.length / 5; i++)
            if (i == 0)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  for (int j = 5 * i; j < min(icon.length, 5 * i + 5); j++) selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: icon[j])
                ],
              )
            else
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    for (int j = 5 * i; j < min(icon.length, 5 * i + 5); j++) selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: icon[j])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
        ]
    )
```

Comment: thanks for your comments, and sorry for my bad explanation, as I was going to generate each rows with using loop as well.

Comment: @SugiuraY it was clear to me. And I do believe my answer also works for your situation. But of course eamirho3ein's  also works well